# selecting only one of the images from a group of images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables let me show you what it looks like,

```
Projects
---------
id

Images
-------
id
projects_id
image
is_default
```

when uploading images for a project, multiple images are uploaded the default image isn't set yet. so when i run the query like this,

```
$projects = Project::leftJoin('images', 'projects.id', '=', 'images.project_id')->get();
```

so if i have 4 images listed in the images table and one record in the projects table, i get a result of 4 projects with the same information using all the different images i used for that project.

How can i Limit it to only show one project record that has is_default set to 1 and if none exists it would show a dummy image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use first() for fech a single record. After fech the data from table to $projects, use the following condition

```
If(count($projects) > 0)
{
 //Image is existing. Use image for for doing something
}else{
//No image found. Use defult image
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In this query check the required conditions.

```
$projects = Project::leftJoin('images', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'images.item_id');
            $join->where('images.is_default', 1);
        })
    ->where('images.is_default', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: yes but when i do that no records show. i want to be able to show the record and if no default image is set for it then show a dummy image.